# Go to next page of laravel pagination automatically when I clicked a button with jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have pagination that used a loop in blade to show a questions of a exam in each page I want to when click on a button, automatically go to next page with jquery and send the data of that question to controller by ajax.
how can I do this, thanks in advance

Comment: This is a very vague and broad question. I recommend you start with the basics. You might get bombarded with negative comments here. This is too broad a question to answer in a small post. I recommend you watch more tutorials.

Comment: thanks, it's done. I used laravel function and get the the url data with jquery and now it works